# Ticks missing in contourf

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot ticks at logarithmic values (without labels, only the ticks). For some reason the following code doesn't plot them (set(gca,'XTick') doesn't do anything):

```
figure1=figure(1)
axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1,'YScale','log','XScale','log');
grid(axes1,'on');
hold(axes1,'on');
[C,h]=contourf(lamx(2:NKX+1),lamz(2:NKZ+1),phi2d(2:NKX+1,2:NKZ+1)',[10],'LineColor','none');
clabel(C,h);
axis tight;    
axis([lamx(end) max(lamx) lamz(end) max(lamz)]) 
xlabel('\lambda_x','Fontsize',20);
ylab=ylabel('\lambda_z','Fontsize',20);
set(gca,'XTick',0.1:0.1:1)
grid on
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode','auto'); 
set(ylab, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [-0.1, 0.5, 0]);
set(gca,'linewidth',1.5,'FontSize',16)
colormap(flipud(gray(256)));
colorbar;  
print('-dpng','-opengl','-r1200','2dspec')
```

[image]

How could the ticks be plotted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ticks in your example are obscured by the `Contour` object itself. The order in which the `Axes` elements are drawn relative to objects within it is controlled with the `Axes` [`Layer`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7_sep_shared-Layer) property.

The default value for this property is `bottom` which means anything like a filled contour drawn in the axes will be drawn on top of the ticks, and you won't be able to see them. The `contourf` function obviously knows this isn't a helpful default for plots that will obscure the ticks in their entirety because it usually changes the property to `top` when you call it – but only when the `Axes` `NextPlot` is set to `replace`. By calling `hold on` you also cause `contourf` to leave that property alone, so it ends up staying at `bottom`.

In your example you can deal with this in one of two ways.

1. As it's currently written, there no intentional effect of the `hold(axes1,'on');` line, because you're only adding one plot. So you could just remove that line if your full code doesn't rely on it. Otherwise,
2. Set the `Layer` property to `top` from the outset when you create the axes:

   ```
   axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1,'YScale','log','XScale','log','Layer','top');
   ```

Comment: What if I want to plot on top of the figure? hold on + plot(whatever) doesn't seem to work

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? If `Layer` is set to `top` the ticks should stay on top even with multiple plots on the axes.

Comment: Yes, I didn't refer to the ticks. I meant that I am not allowed to plot another curve on top of this one by doing the classic hold on + new plot and I think it may be due to the same problem I had with the ticks, maybe I am not setting the plot priorities correctly

Comment: This sounds like a completely separate problem that might be the subject of a new question if you can reduce it to a suitable minimal example. It's hard to tell from the way you describe it though as "not allowed" is rather mysterious and vague.